# Given load resistance with max power, how to find specific resistance within source

Tags: circuit-analysis

So I'm having a bit of a struggle with this question, at least maybe I'm misreading or misunderstanding it.  As at least from My understanding of maximum power is different, as with R2 being the resistance it is, R1 in both cases should be 0hms ideally to make R source and R load equivalent to get as close to max power as possible.

This seems wrong, but maybe I'm just approaching this question the totally wrong way.  Or my notes on the subject/looking it up don't quite give me a clear idea how to approach it and am continuing to see a incorrect method.

As trying to use thevenins and approach the circuit from the right doesn't seem to give me values I'd want, if I approach from the left and use R1+R2//R3 then I can actually make max power.

---

[image: Question]

Comment: Why stop at 0 ohms?

Comment: Can it be negative?

Comment: 0 Ohms looks good to me. Maybe you get 6 points for spotting a trick question?

Comment: I think your instructor was trying to be clever with a question about Thevenin equivalent circuits, and swapped R1 and R4 in the question. It makes much more sense if you are given the value of R1 and have to find the value of R4 that results in maximum power transfer.

Comment: Oh they were, it was 0.  I let myself overthink it and read way to much into the details and get hung up on the wording.

That much was obvious to me when I saw it initially just seemed like a non-question so figured I must have been doing something wrong or missed something.  Guess will keep an eye out now for these kinds of trick questions from him lol that are trying to make ya think

Answer (score 1):

You have to ask yourself; *"Is my teacher a mathematician, or an engineer?"*

- An engineer, like the other answer by Jan, says, "the best I can do is zero ohms", because an engineer knows that negative resistors are hard to come by.
- A mathematician is happy with negative answers, because in this case, you have a nice unique solution for both (a) and (b) resistor values.

Infinite power is available for R4 with a negative resistor of the correct value at R1. You solve the total positive resistance to the right of R1, and then make R1 negative so that the 100V source sees a total resistance of zero-ohms. An engineer knows that this solution is not practical. But an engineer also knows that negative resistance is a useful tool - it can be fabricated with some active circuitry, and it also exists in some devices.

Power for any negative resistance has to come from somewhere. For an active negative resistor, it comes from its own power supply. For a natural negative resistance of a device, it comes from its bias supply. This would apply to discharge tubes, Gunn diode, Esaki diodes...without external power, negative resistance is latent.

Comment: Original answer... that is why it was not upvoted... I don't think a teacher needs to be a great mathematician or an engineer... they just need to have common sense not to ask such pointless questions. As for the "active negative resistor", we must clearly say that it is just a circuit that behaves as a "proportional source" of a voltage V = I.R or a current I = V/R... while the "natural negative resistor" is just a "dynamic resistor" that regulates ("amplifies") the power like any active device like transistor. Thus it can be seen how the power of the supply source is applied to the load...

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all we know that the power in resistor \$\text{R}_4\$ is given by:

$$\text{P}_{\text{R}_4}=\text{V}_{\text{R}_4}\cdot\text{I}_{\text{R}_4}\tag1$$

We know Ohm's law:

$$\text{V}_{\text{R}_4}=\text{I}_{\text{R}_4}\cdot\text{R}_4\tag2$$

And we also can use the current divider formula, in order to write:

$$\text{I}_{\text{R}_4}=\frac{\text{R}_3}{\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4}\cdot\text{I}_\text{in}\tag3$$

Now, using Ohm's law again, we get:

$$\text{V}_\text{in}=\text{I}_\text{in}\cdot\text{R}_\text{in}\tag4$$

And:

$$\text{R}_\text{in}=\text{R}_1+\frac{\text{R}_3\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_4\right)}{\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4}\tag5$$

Combining all the formulas above, gives us:

$$\text{P}_{\text{R}_4}=\left(\frac{\text{R}_3}{\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4}\cdot\frac{\text{V}_\text{in}}{\text{R}_1+\frac{\text{R}_3\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_4\right)}{\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4}}\right)^2\cdot\text{R}_4\tag6$$

Now, using the given values we get:

$$\text{P}_{\text{R}_4}=\frac{6250000\text{R}_4}{\left(25\left(75+\text{R}_4\right)+\text{R}_1\left(100+\text{R}_4\right)\right)^2}\tag7$$

> Now, you can see that the denominator of the fraction, in formula \$(7)\$, needs to stay as small as possible in order to get the maximum power in resistor \$\text{R}_4\$. We can conclude that when \$\text{R}_1=0\$ gives the most amound of power:
>
> $$\text{P}_{\text{R}_4}=\frac{10000\text{R}_4}{\left(75+\text{R}_4\right)^2}\tag8$$

Answer (score 0):

The question is incorrect because maximum power is achieved by adjusting the load resistance (R4) at a given output resistance (R1) of the source... and not by adjusting the resistance of the source (R1) at a given load resistance (R4). In the latter case, the answer is always R1 = 0, regardless of R4.